# UIAlertController ActionSheet issue over iOS9

Tags: iphone, swift, uialertview, ios9

I have got an issue with the UIAlertController over iOS9... it was good over ios8, but now it give me the next result:
[image: Action Sheet issue]

It's work fine with Alert style, but with the ActionSheet style it works strange, and drops the following error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "=10)]>",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-10-09 16:41:29.613
>   OnskeskyenShareExtension[53993:14714610] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "=12)-[UIView:0x7f8f69cde5e0]   (Names:
>   '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8f69cddec0 )>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

My code is:

```
func createActionPicker(){
            self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
            self.alertController.modalInPopover = false;
            for i in 0...self.listData.count-1{
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: self.listData[i], style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction:UIAlertAction) in
                    self.dropDownListText.text = alertAction.title;
                    for j in 0...self.alertController.actions.count-1{
                        if(alertAction.isEqual(self.alertController.actions[j])){
                            self.selectedIndex = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                self.alertController.addAction(action);
            }
            self.alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil));
            let alertView = UIView(frame: self.frame);
            self.addSubview(alertView)
    }

public func dropDown(sender:UIView)
{
    if(self.listData.count == 0) {return}
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
    {
        self.popover.presentPopoverFromRect(self.dropDownButton.frame, inView: self, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, animated: true);
    }

    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.viewController.presentViewController(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        });
    }
}
```

Anyone could help me to solve this annoying issue?!

Comment: did you get solution for this? I am struggling since 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "your message here", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear message history", style: .Destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
}))

presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it works perfectly for me on iOS9